# How to import Json data into Postgres table

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I have an API that gives json data text file called **corporateHoliday.txt**.

The data look like this:

```
{
    "holiday_id":"1712010100000104",
    "holiday_date":"2018-12-30 00:00:00.0",
    "holiday_description":"SUNDAY",
    "holiday_status":"A"
},
{
    "holiday_id":"1712010100000103",
    "holiday_date":"2018-12-29 00:00:00.0",
    "holiday_description":"SATURDAY",
    "holiday_status":"A"
}
```

My postgres table attributes look like this **t_leave_holida(objectid, holiday_date,description,recstatus)**

I want to import these json data from txt file into the postgres database table?

Comment: & what you've tried to insert that data to your postgres db?

Comment: eventually that json data file is from other source, I need to import to my local postgres database.

Comment: Just read the content from file as `$string` using `file_get_contents()`, decode your `$string` to `array` using `json_decode($string,1);`, then loop through the `$array` using `foreach` and insert the data to postgresql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `jsonb` type and just select data from json, like here:

```
db=# create table t_leave_holida(objectid bigint, holiday_date timestamp(1), description text,recstatus text);
db=# insert into t_leave_holida select (d->>'holiday_id')::bigint, (d->>'holiday_date')::timestamp, d->>'holiday_description', d->>'holiday_status' from (select '{
    "holiday_id":"1712010100000104",
    "holiday_date":"2018-12-30 00:00:00.0",
    "holiday_description":"SUNDAY",
    "holiday_status":"A"
}'::jsonb d) ali;
INSERT 0 1
db=# select * from t_leave_holida;
     objectid     |    holiday_date     | description | recstatus
------------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------
 1712010100000104 | 2018-12-30 00:00:00 | SUNDAY      | A
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a json array we can insert all records in t_leave_holida

```
  insert into t_leave_holida(objectid, holiday_date,description,recstatus)
  select holiday_id,holiday_date,holiday_description,holiday_status from
  json_to_recordset(
   '[
      {
        "holiday_id":"1712010100000104",
        "holiday_date":"2018-12-30 00:00:00.0",
        "holiday_description":"SUNDAY",
        "holiday_status":"A"
      },
      {
        "holiday_id":"1712010100000103",
        "holiday_date":"2018-12-29 00:00:00.0",
        "holiday_description":"SATURDAY",
        "holiday_status":"A"
      }
    ]'
  ) as x(holiday_id bigint, holiday_date date, holiday_description text,holiday_status text);
```